# How to use 'OctreePointCloudAdjacency' to get list of adjacent voxels

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I can create the octree data structure successfully. Then, I have to get adjacent voxel list for each voxel in the octree. I tried to use OctreePointCloudAdjacency but the returned indexVector has size 0. Could you please help me about getting list of adjacent voxels?
I am looking forward to hearing from you
Thanks in advance

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
//read pcd file
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("FARO_SCAN010203_SEMI_DIAGONAL - Cloud.pcd", *cloud);
//voxel dimension
float resolution;
std::cout << "Voxel buyuklugu m cinsinden girin." << std::endl;
std::cin >> resolution;
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree(resolution);
octree.setInputCloud(cloud);

octree.setInputCloud(cloud);
octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();
std::cout << "Number of voxels: " << octree.getLeafCount() << std::endl;

std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ>> pointGrid;
octree.getOccupiedVoxelCenters(pointGrid);

//get adjacent voxels of a voxel
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudAdjacency<pcl::PointXYZ > deneme(resolution);
deneme.setInputCloud(cloud);
deneme.addPointsFromInputCloud();
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudAdjacencyContainer<pcl::PointXYZ> *leaf_container;
leaf_container = deneme.getLeafContainerAtPoint(cloud->points[1000]);

std::cout << "leaf container size =" << leaf_container->size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "leaf_container number of meighbors =" << leaf_container->getNumNeighbors() << std::endl;
std::cout << "leaf container point counter =" << leaf_container->getPointCounter() << std::endl;
std::cout << "leaf container size2 =" << leaf_container->getSize() << std::endl;
pcl::IndicesPtr indexVectorXX(new std::vector <int>);
leaf_container->getPointIndices(*indexVectorXX);
std::cout << "index vector size =" << indexVectorXX->size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Maybe you should tell your readers where you get functions such as "OctreePointCloudAdjacency" from. We are not mind readers, you know, and that function is *not* part of standard C++ that you can expect everyone to know about.

Comment: It is a class implemented in PCL (point cloud library). I read related documentation but I can not get the indices.

Comment: Can you post the output of your program please?

Comment: @user887912 Have a look here: http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1octree_1_1_octree_container_base.html#a7411fb5b034a61ed33b2c05c6591ef38 
The default `LeafContainerT` is `OctreePointCloudAdjacencyContainer`, which has no implementation for `getPointIndices` (see link).  
You have to provide your own `LeafContainerT` in order to store the indices of the leaf's neighbours.